# DeepLearning4J How can I add layers dynamically to a multi layer netowrk

Tags: neural-network, deeplearning4j

I'm trying to test several combinations of multilayer networks, but the Network configuration Builder doesn't allow adding or removing layers after the build.

If someone can give me a hint, thanks in advance.

Comment: The transfer learning api is what you're looking for: https://github.com/eclipse/deeplearning4j-examples/tree/master/dl4j-examples/src/main/java/org/deeplearning4j/examples/advanced/features/transferlearning

Comment: Probably I didn't explain myself correctly.
Based on the number of inputs and training rows, I want to create each layer with certain parameters. That configuration of each layer will be different, amount of neurons, nr of layers, etc. 
I don't know how can I decouple the Builder to do this separately in a for loop and add it again to the MultiLayerNetworkConfiguration.
Sorry, but the example you gave, I can't relate to this.
Thank you anyway. :/ @AdamGibson

Comment: @AdamGibson For example I can do this in DeepNetts like this:
        nc.neuralNet = FeedForwardNetwork.builder()
                .addInputLayer(d.inputs[0].length)
    ----->    .addFullyConnectedLayers(nc.hiddenActivationType, hiddenLayers.stream().mapToInt(i -> i).toArray())
                .addOutputLayer(d.outputs[0].length, nc.outputActivationType)
             .....
                .build();

How can I do something similar with DL4J?

Answer (score 0):

I got it!

This did the trick
**.list(layers.toArray(new DenseLayer[layers.size()]))**

```
System.out.println("CREATING NETWORK.");
        List<Integer> hiddenLayers = NetworkSizeCalculator.getNetwork(nc.networkStructure, d.inputs[0].length, d.inputs.length);
        List<DenseLayer> layers=new ArrayList<>();
        for(int i=0;i<hiddenLayers.size();i++){
            layers.add(new DenseLayer.Builder()
                    .nIn(hiddenLayers.get(i))
                    .nOut(hiddenLayers.get(i))
                    .weightInit(WeightInit.XAVIER)
                    .activation((Activation) nc.hiddenActivationType)
                    .build());
        }

        MultiLayerConfiguration configuration = new NeuralNetConfiguration.Builder()
                .seed(randomSeed)
                .updater(t.getOptimizer())
                .activation(nc.hiddenActivationType)
                .weightInit(WeightInit.XAVIER)
                .list(layers.toArray(new DenseLayer[layers.size()]))
                .layer(hiddenLayers.size(),new OutputLayer.Builder()
                        .nIn(d.inputs[0].length)
                        .nOut(d.outputs[0].length)
                        .weightInit(WeightInit.XAVIER)
                        .activation((Activation) nc.outputActivationType)
                        .lossFunction(LossFunctions.LossFunction.MSE)
                        .build()).build();

        MultiLayerNetwork network = new MultiLayerNetwork(configuration);
```